# How to setup a custom keybinding to run a script or execute a command in Atom editor?

Tags: key-bindings, atom-editor

Is it possible to make `CMD+T` keybinding run a bash script? Like for example i want to run my tests on my Heroku project, the command `python manage.py test` would be run if did `CMD+T`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Click on **Packages** --> **Commmand Palette** --> Select  **Toggle**.
2. Type **Install Packages and Themes**.
3. Search for **process-palette** and then install it.
4. Click on **Packages** --> **Process Palette** --> Select  **Toggle**
5. Create a global configuration or a project specific configuration with the respective **Do it!** buttons. It will create an example configuration file and open it in the graphical editor
6. From the graphical editor, you can then configure the command you want and assign a shortcut to it :

[image: graphical editor]

[Process-palette documentation](https://github.com/morassman/process-palette)